# All my company's server names start with "SW", what does it stand for? Is it same case in all companies?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, server

Almost all my companies server names start with "SW". I'm wondering what "SW" stands for.

Also, looks like production servers start with "SWPV", test servers start with "SWTV". I'm wondering if "PV"/"TV" here mean production version/test version.

The question may not be so relevent and I'm not a server engineer either... I heard people say "SW" means software.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.   You should ask internally at your company if you have questions about your naming convention.

Comment: SW means scallywag to me, south west to many, software to some, and SW to most. I'm sure your server folks can help you... they determine the host name and naming convention most of the time. :)

Comment: Its a naming convention and has nothing really to do with programming or anything, your servers could all be prefixed with BOB it wouldnt matter, check with your company

Comment: IF SW does not stand for Software, then it is likely specific to your company's name, division, or function.  Your DBA or anybody who has been with your company a long time should be able to assist.  Otherwise, take a look at the list of 102 items with a SW acronym at the following link.  Perhaps something will jump out: https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/SW

Comment: how about [S]tackoverflo[W]

Comment: You should ask internally first if you have not already. The community is unlikely to know what the naming schema of a server means and you are likely to get a lot of sarcastic answers along the way. Voted to close.

Comment: Flagged as "should be closed".  This has nothing to do with SSIS or SQL Server development.  This is a question for your systems people.

Answer (score 0):

In most big companies  it is the data centre location acronym ... Allowing for easy identification of servers

Also

```
PV - Production Virtual
TV - Test Virtual
```